# PagePiling.js delay before section starts to move

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagepiling.js

Is there a possibility to prevent pagePiling.js from moving the current pp-section when mousewheel is fired? Or even better, to force start moving after a delay?

My current issue is that i want to show an animation inside the pp-section before the pp-section starts to move. And for that i need a delay. Maybe I need something like an event beforeLoad which isn´t implemented there.

I work the first time with pagepiling.js so maybe i just dont think the right way, because i also didnt find any questions about this or a similar issue online. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The plugin doesn't provide any way to do so I'm afraid. Its big brother fullPage.js does, in case you want to consider it.